# Grails createCriteria on abstract domain

Tags: grails, inheritance, groovy, grails-orm, abstract-class

I am quite curious how one would use the criteria builder to access fields of an inherited class.

Let's assume we have the following class:

```
class A { 
  String fieldOne 
  String fieldTwo

  static hasMany = [childs: AbstractChildClass]

}
```

and the abstract child class would look like this:

```
abstract class AbstractChildClass {

  Integer valueOne
  Integer valueTwo
  A a

  static mapping
      tablePerHierarchy false
  }
}
```

of course there are several extending classes such as:

```
class ExtendingClassOne extends AbstractChildClass {

    DesiredObject desiredObject

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }

}
```

let's also assume there is the class DesiredObject which looks like this:

```
class DesiredObject {
    String infoA
    String infoB
}
```

The question is how one would get the fields infoA and infoB by creating a criteria for class A. My approach so far is this:

```
A.createCriteria().list {
    childs {
        desiredObject {
            ilike('infoA', '%something%')
        }
    }
}
```

This of course does not work because in the table ExtendingClassOne is only the id of the desiredObject and I have no clue how to join the object with the criteria builder to get its fields.

Thank you for reading.

Marco

Answer (score 2):

don't expect 100% match between your domain model and the DB schema it's related to.

In your case the polymorphism would work only with `tablePerHierarchy true` for AbstractChildClass.

If you do want to stick with `tablePerHierarchy false`, you can define your class like:

```
class A { 

  static hasMany = [ childrenOne:ExtendingClassOne, childrenTwo:ExtendingClassTwo ]

}
```

thus your query would be as simple as:

```
A.withCriteria{
  for( String c in [ 'childrenOne', 'childrenTwo' ] ){
    "$c"{
      desiredObject {
        ilike('infoA', '%something%')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I can't change the model as there are quite a lot of extending classes which could also have children I want to get fields from. I hope there is a more elegant way than building own SQL queries.

Comment: don't uber-engineer your domain model :)