# Querying relationships with extended domain classes

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a few domain classes:

```
class Dealer {
    hasMany = [vehicles: Vehicle]
}

class Vehicle {
    belongsTo = [dealer: Dealer]
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
}

class Bus extends Vehicle {
    belongsTo = [liabilityInsurance: LiabilityInsurance]
}

class LiabilityInsurance {
    hasMany = [buses: Bus]
}
```

I'd like to make a criteria query (or a HQL one) which will find all `Dealer`s from have sold a `Vehicle` (a `Bus`) which has `LiabilityInsurance`.

I'm having trouble because I cannot traverse the relationships top-down:

```
Dealer.withCriteria {
   vehicle {
      eq 'liabilityInsurance', foo  // error, vehicle doesn't have liabilityInsurance
   }
}
```

Any idea how to do this?

EDIT:

Similar problem are mentioned [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/CriteriaBuilder-dealing-with-inheritance-td2529446.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544648/grails-createcriteria-on-abstract-domain).

Comment: String query="select new map(d as dealer, v as vehicle) from Vehicle v left join Dealer d where d.vehicles=v"     
   def result = Dealer.executeQuery(query, [max: 20, offset: 0])

Comment: @vahid the query does not mention `liabilityInsurance` at all, but that is my search criteria...

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Grails syntax, so I will offer a solution with pure JPA; you can translate it to Grails if you find it useful:

```
select distinct d from Dealer d join d.vehicles v
where v in (select b from Bus b where b.liabilityInsurance = foo)
```

If you have more vehicles with liability insurance (other than `Bus`), you would preferably extend them from a base class which extends `Vehicle` and defines `liabilityInsurance`. Then you would reference the base class in the `in` clause. If that would not fit in your design, you can repeat the `in` clause for each such entity:

```
...
or v in (select a from Airplane a where a.liabilityInsurance = foo)
```

However, if it is only the `Bus` with the liability insurance, then the easiest way to do it is:

```
select distinct b.dealer from Bus b where b.liabilityInsurance = foo
```